# How to protect underground tank water from insects and Algae?

Tags: water, algae

We have underground tanks for water storage, but they are affected by algae and small water insects.  I want to protect the water from these. The water is for general life use, except drinking, like washing clothes gardening etc.

Are there some sustainable ways to get rid of the algae and insects?

Comment: Can you clarify **which** other uses?  Watering the garden?  Washing clothes?  Toilet?

Comment: Inner temperature is very important - do you know it? In what climate are you? What's the depth where the tanks are located? Is there any chance of light shedding inside?

Comment: @PeterIvan this tank is underground not possible to shed sun light and here temprature is near about 25' to 35' ..

Comment: If the temperature is above 25°C, then you are in a serious risk of growing [legionella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legionella#Source_control). The water is not used for drinking, but still it's very different from a mild-climate-located tank whose temperature wouldn't rise above 15°C throughout the year. My primary concern in your situation would be protecting people from harm (sustainability shouldn't cease life) by some water treatment. The secondary aim would be doing it in a sustainable way.

Comment: Yadav, if you answer a question in comments, please also [edit] that into your question. It should contain all relevant information; comments can disappear.

Answer (score 1):

We have a community well that stores its water in underground tanks. Every three years, we empty the tanks and clean the algae out. Also, we add a tiny amount of chlorine to the water through an automated system to help kill any dangerous bacteria. Tiny trace amounts.

But if you aren't drinking this water, do the bugs and algae really matter?

Comment: Even if you were drinking this water bugs and algae would probably be lower on the list of concerns.  I imagine the water that comes through the municipal pipes is probably in worse shape.  Why not add a series of filters in line to where the water comes into the house.  A prefilter for the large stuff, a finer filter for the small stuff then a UV filter to kill anything that might have gotten through those?  This way you can clean out the tank every few years without worrying too much about what's going on in there in the meantime.